# how to execute the content given to a variable dynamically

Tags: java, c, perl

I have one program which takes a set of statements into a variable,
and how can i place that block of code(which is given into a variable as string) dynamically into present executing code for compilation and execution.
i am eagerly waiting for this solution.
any programming language having this facility..
if yes please paste the code for this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl makes this simple.

In Perl:

```
eval q{ print "Hello world!\n" };
```

or

```
$code = ' print "Hello world!\n"; ';
eval $code;
```

See [eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html).

Note, you should be careful where you get your code from.  You're exposing the full power of your language to whoever provides you with the input.  Make sure it's coming from a safe source.  **"string eval", as it's called, is high risk behavior in any language that supports it.**  Accepting input from a web user and running it as code on your server, for example, is just asking for a disaster.

With respect to C: C is a compiled language, and the compiler isn't available at run-time.  On the other hand, there's nothing stopping you from embedding a Perl interpreter in a C program, which would give you run-time compilation and execution of Perl code from within your compiled C application.  For the record, C++ is in the same boat.  It's a compiled language, and the compiler isn't a component of the runtime environment.

As for Java, there's this article: [The Java 6.0 Compiler API](http://www.javabeat.net/2007/04/the-java-6-0-compiler-api/).

Comment: @user1736927: Has your question been answered?  What else can we clear up for you?

Comment: Then go ahead an click the "check" box, and accept someone's answer (This will be your first accepted answer, having asked four, so it's time to figure out how to do it.)  Pick whichever one you feel answered it for you.

Comment: If you need to `eval` a string with restricted rights, you can use the `Safe` module to specify exactly which functions your code may call.

Comment: @amon Safe can only go so far.  It can't prevent DOS through long-running processes, or through consuming tons of memory, for example.  See the "RISKS" heading in its POD.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said "any language", I'll ignore your tags.

In Python it's trivial:

```
code = "print \"hello world\""
exec code
```

This will print "hello world".

C does not have such a facility, since the compiler is not present at run-time.

Comment: is it possible for us to pass that block of code through a flat file by url or by uploading or by importing into the program

Comment: @user1736927: You want to accept a file from a web-based user and execute it as code on your server?  This is possible in just about any scripting language, including Perl and Python, but it's way beyond unwise.

Comment: @user1736927, yes you can do that.  Anything that can be put into a string can be executed.  However, this is a big potential security issue.  You had better be sure that your input is coming from a trusted source.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [javaScript `eval()` Function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.ASP)

Comment: is it possible for us to pass that block of code using keyboard or any flat file format to eval() during runtime

Comment: then just tell me the procedure of doing this process or if available please paste the code here

Comment: i already read that link in w3schools and i want the code how to upload a document and use it in eval()

Comment: @user1736927, the link already gives a code example. This site is to meant to help you, not do your work for you.  Please stop demanding that others write your code.